# Changing the customer/account layout to 2columns-left in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, login, page-layouts

I was easily able to make my entire site in Magento 2 from the default to 2columns-left by a few simple changes in the admin section.

I created my own theme with the fallback of the luna theme. All overrides and modifications were done in my new theme only.

However, when it comes to the customer/account/login page, it appears as a single column page with the login section at the top and the left menu bar spans the entire bottom of the screen.

How do I change the account/login page and the account/create pages to a 2column-left layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just override `customer_account_login.xml` and `customer_account_create.xml` file to your theme customer layout.

File path for make customer login page 2columns-left,

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

File path for make customer account create page 2columns-left,

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body/>
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed the override for customer_account_create. That did the trick.